# Constructor Not Defined

Tags: unit-test, controller

I'm trying to write a unit test for a controller and I'm stuck at this error "Constructor not defined"

Controller

```
public Part__c getPartLookup() {
    if (partLookup == null) {
        partLookup = new Part__c();
    }
    return partLookup;
}
```

Test Class(what I have)

```
 Part__c pts=new Part__c(Opportunity__c=op.id,Product__c=p.id,Customer_Part__c='12345');
insert pts;


ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(pts);
    PartSelectionController controller = new PartSelectionController(sc);

    Test.startTest();
    Part__c result = controller.getPartLookup();
    Test.stopTest();
```

Any Ideas?

Edit

This is my full controller 
https://gist.github.com/EricSSH/d6a3d9f88b835719efb9

Comment: can u post ur complete controller code ? in your controller do u hv a constructor accepting standard controller as a parameter ?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Updated Question, I don't want to put the entire controller on here, so I put it on my Gist (It's over 1k lines)

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use a `StandardController`, you are actually writing an `Extesion`, and you need to define a constructor that accepts `ApexPages.StandardController` as a parameter.

```
public PartSelectionController(ApexPages.StandardController)
{
    // initialize some stuff
}
```

Comment: This controller was written by a contractor awhile back, and he never wrote a unit test.  I'm trying to pick up the pieces in order to clean up production, this controller is way beyond my skill set..  I should change my controller then?

Comment: Yes, add these lines at the very top (you can remove the comment line).

Comment: I updated my question, and It is accepting StandardControllers.  There another method called getQuote() which is accepting it

Comment: Is that an additional question?

Comment: No it's me saying that yours answers isn't an answer